# after build tables run php file

Tags: php, mysql, function

i have small system and i try make its easy and faster
i make all build table on one place but after this (install.php) i want
this run (index.php)
i'm sure i miss somthing need littel help her

```
$sqle = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
id INT(11) NOT NULL, 
full_name VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1"
;

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}
if ($conn->query($sqle) === TRUE) {
$response = file_get_contents("index.php");
 } else {
echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}


$conn->close();


?>
```

Comment: undefined variable for the first one. where is `$sql`  coming from?

Comment: btw, you should make your `id` an AI'd column instead.

Comment: Just include index.php in the last line

Comment: `if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)` will never happen. Question's unclear in regards to that.

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== TRUE`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have that run on your index page `include` it in your code. This will call the script, and given that the requirements are met, it should run and create that new table.

```
<?php include 'install.php'; ?>
```

Also, note that your SQL statement is under the variable of `$sqle`. You are calling the variable `$sql` in your query statement.

Comment: *"You are calling the variable sql in your prepared statement."* - There is no prepared statement, just a regular query. This comment as per the original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46286304/1

Comment: thanks for your answer
about the $sql and $sqle
this only way this php build both table
i try find anther way but didn't find...

now <?php include 'install.php'; ?> 
u mean i need put this on index.php file?

Comment: @idobeker yes, put `include` in your index page

Comment: i fix that with 

if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {